# Sorting AWS CLI objects listing from S3 bucket by Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way for AWS CLI to return `ls` results sorted alphabetically by `Name` column? In other words, do the sorting on the whole bucket and then return resulting objects, because I'm using `--page-size` argument to truncate number of results (doing a sort of pagination with offset, since AWS CLI doesn't offer that out-of-the-box)?

I have a bucket of images and each image has `Name` column.

Current command for listing objects with `sort_by` query that does not work (it returns all objects, but sort is not applied):

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_path --page-size page_size --query "sort_by(@, &Name)" --summarize
```

Also, what is default sort for objects when listing bucket?

I'm getting results formatted like this:

```
2023-08-09 09:49:08    7031141 image_name.jpg
```

but they aren't sorted neither by `LastModified` date, nor by `Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLI output command results can be filtered client-side using queries, as stated in the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html), whereas filters are applied server-side.

Queries operate using the [JMESPath standard](https://jmespath.org/) for managing paths and queries on JSON structures, but the s3 CLI **ls** command doesn't handle JSON output.

You can use **list-object** instead e.g. sorted by the Key (a.k.a. name) field:

```bash
$ aws --output json s3api list-objects --bucket ${bucket_name} --query "sort_by(Contents, &Key)"
```

Comment: Is it possible to get total objects number with `s3api` (just like with `--summarize`on `ls`)?

Comment: you can do it client-side with the query --query "length(Contents)

Comment: Yes, there's not a summarize option in list-objects, but you can use ls to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `aws s3 ls`, which attempts to provide a Linux-like listing, use:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name
```

This will *always* return results sorted by the `Key` of the object. Note that the Key includes the **full path** of the object (including subdirectories).

The [`list-objects-v2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) call directly maps to the API call used to list objects in S3 and it returns the raw data provided by S3.

The default response will be JSON, but you can modify it to just get the Key:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --query 'Contents[].[Key]' --output text
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the sorting (as from @Filippo's answer), but firstly to make all `Key`s lowercase? Because it seems that sorting is case-sensitive,  and I need it case-insensitive